# How will Firebase handle passwordless authentication without Dynamic Links?

Tags: firebase

Setting up a new React Native project with Firebase passwordless authentication, I see this warning:

> Note: Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated and should not be used in new projects. The service will shut down on August 25, 2025.
> You will have at least 12 months from the announcement date to migrate.

See: https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq

In the future, will passwordless authentication instead leverage [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) and [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/)?

From the perspective of a developer accustomed to doing this with Dynamic Links, and reading the standard docs for implementing the email auth link in [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#configuring_firebase_dynamic_links) or [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth#configuring_firebase_dynamic_links), I'm confused how to proceed implementing passwordless authentication in a new project.

Answer (score 8):

*firebaser here*

Thanks for the raising the question. Firebase Authentication email link auth indeed currently uses Firebase Dynamic Links to customize Authentication links.

For now, your email sign-in will continue to work and we will have an update in place to continue email sign-in functionality by the time the Firebase Dynamic Links service is shut down.

We've updated the [FAQ doc linked](https://firebase.google.com/support/dynamic-links-faq) above to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. An architectural debate is still raging inside Google, and the broader community eagerly awaits details! I see from the updated docs that we "will have at least 12 months from the announcement date to migrate" after the announcement in Q3 2023. But I'm torn about accepting an answer here until we have said details.